# NextJS & Supabase - Wrong redirecting in auth routes

Tags: next.js13, supabase, render.com

I have my app with nextjs and supabase deployed on render.com. All works as expected in local, but in prod, supabase redirects to http://localhost:10000 after login. Actually all my auth routes after supabase interaction are wrongly redirected.

I saw a PORT variable in render.com which is settled to 10000, but removing it causes no changes, as it is apparently a default variable.

Some more specifics:

1. sign-in route in nexts:
   [image: nextJS (auth)/routes/sign-in]
2. The marked console.log above, logs this on my render.com server when on production
   [image: server logs]
3. Authentications/URL Configuration in Supabase dashboard:
   [image: supabase url-configs]
4. My middleware.ts file:
   [image: middleware.ts]
5. the req of the middleware on the server:
   [image: middleware req]
6. the res of the middleware on the server:
   [image: middleware res]

I very much appreciate any help on this, thanks!

I tried:
signing in in production.
I expect:
to be redirected to https://circulart-statistics.onrender.com/clients. Instead I am redirected to http://localhost:10000/clients. Same happens for any other auth-redirects from supabase.

Comment: Since there are no mentions of `localhost:10000` anywhere within the Supabase auth configuration page, I'm guessing the cause is somewhere within render.com configuration. I'm not too familiar with render.com, but is there like a `site URL` type of setting that you perhaps haven't updated?

Comment: Very right. I just changed my app to deploy into vercel and it just worked as it should. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is apparently some issues at render.com running the version I am using of Next JS (v13.5.4) and node 18.18.2.

It worked perfectly when I tried deploying into vercel.